# XCUIElementType differ for simulator and real device when inspecting in appium

Tags: appium, simulator, xcuitest

When I inspect a element in simulator for ex. page title, the element type shown is `XCUIElementTypeStaticText` however when I search the same element in real iOS device, `XCUIElementTypeStaticText` does not work instead I have to replace it to `XCUIElementTypeOther` for appium to idenfity the element.

Can someone please explain why it happens and is there anyway to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is you have different iOS versions on your device and Simulator.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. will check.

Comment: Checked and it is due to different iOS version. Is there any workaround instead of using accessibiltiy id.

Comment: You can use your localization keys as identifiers. It is more stable than labels but less stable than IDs. https://www.pixeldock.com/blog/how-to-use-your-localizable-strings-in-your-xcode-uitests/